# Set API URL for Quasar in the Electron mode build

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder, quasar-framework, electron-packager

I want to set my API URL for Electron mode.
When I built my code to Electron production mode, All of my API URLs disappear first of the URL such as this: `file:///core/v1/api/main/login`

How can I set my API URL(an external IP address) for Electron mode in Production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. for this case, we could change the `axios.js` in the boot directory.

For example, I need to change the `baseURL` to another when I build to Electron mode.

```
if (process.env.MODE === 'electron') {
  var axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL
  })
  Vue.prototype.$axios = axiosInstance
} else {
  Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
}
```

Comment: For anyone finding this - it assumes you have the API_URL configured in your .env to load via mix by prefacing with MIX_ like so: MIX_API_URL="${APP_URL}"  or MIX_API_URL=https://example.com/api